# User reverted my edits, moderator declined custom flags

Tags: discussion, support, edits, flags, declined-flags

I've edited two questions where users reverted my edits. Reverted edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44992046/7
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44710868/6

I've raised custom flags with message "User reverted my edits."

Both flags were declined

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Am I doing something wrong? If yes, what should I do instead?

#### Update

OK, thank you guys for valid points about my mistakes.

1. I've added CSS to first post (although it was from OP's CodePen).
2. I didn't substantiate reasons to mod's intervention.

But is this all?

Comment: on that first edit it looks like you changed a lot in their CSS, the second edit is OK-ish.

Comment: @rene Just copy-pasted from user's CodePen (user provided link under HTML/CSS). By if I reapply edit without this CSS and user will revert it again, what should I do?

Comment: Anyway, OPS have the feature now to reverse your edits if they disagree. If so, I would either leave a comment or move on. If they don't want your edits so be it. Trying to force your view of things on posts by a moderator is a waste of flags.

Comment: For the most part, the author of a post has final say in what goes into their post.  So don't get into edit wars with the OP.  Moderator flags are rarely warranted for these kinds of disagreements.  You should only flag otherwise problematic content (rollback to offensive, vandalism etc).

Comment: @rene User reverted code snipperts (and it's much more comfotable to see results in code snippet). Also second post has poor code formatting. Why is it OK to remain poor formatting and remove code snippets?

Comment: I dunno know, ask the OP.

Comment: Vadim: "Mod! User reverted my edits!" Mod: "And why should I care?" Vadim: "But the edits were mine!" that's not a reason to get a mod involved.  At least you have to tell them *why* they should intervene.

Comment: @Will OK, so if I write in custom flags about reverting to poor formatting then moderator would react another way?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov First off, you didn't just make the code snippets, you edited the code itself, which alone merits a rollback.  Second, just because you personally prefer a particular markup for a post doesn't mean that everyone else is obligated to agree; when it comes to matters of opinion, it's the author's opinion that wins.  Now if they're reverting a clear mistake, like say fixing a spelling error or something, that's different, but also not what happened here.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov If you provide a reason for why the rollback was wrong, they can consider whether or not that reason is valid.  If you give no reason at all, there isn't even anything for them to consider in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I declined those flags because I saw no reason to intervene.

In general, moderators only step in with edits in cases where there's outright vandalism, people getting into rollback wars, or something more serious. Owners of posts have the ability to roll back edits on their own posts, and that happens all the time.

Sometimes they don't understand why something was edited, sometimes the edits were against their intentions or style, and so on. As a fairly recent change, owners of posts (and moderators) can now retroactively reject approved edits (which is probably how you noticed this) but that's the same as rolling back an edit.

If you really feel the edits provide significant benefit to the post, you could leave a constructive comment explaining how those edits would improve them. If the author agreed, they could either roll back to your edits or allow you to submit the edits again. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it and move on to something else.

Comment: So rollback #2 is OK even though user reverted code snippet and code formatting? If yes, this means that all users can have poorly formatted posts and don't allow anybody to edit it.

Comment: @Vadim there's nothing stopping you from downvoting such posts

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov The OP(s) in question may not be familiar with what precisely you did.  I see that you haven't even attempted to contact them about your edit.  Try doing that first, and telling them what you improved and why you did so.

Comment: *So rollback #2 is OK even though user reverted code snippet and code formatting?* I like stack snippets but the site rules don't obligate anyone to use them. They exist as a convenience. The indenting is poor but doesn't render the code unreadable. (You also left in the ellipsis abuse and left the alt text as "enter image description here".) It's not that it's OK to leave posts in bad shape in general, it's that this post isn't in such terrible shape to be worth mod attention.

Comment: @BradLarson [this is his edits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yKZ4.png) looks like he is trying to destroy the post

Comment: Downvoting seems like an incorrect action as that is showing the answer is not a useful answer.

Comment: What I find more painful is reverts where [the change is approved then reverted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16965381) (no reason provided). I only hope that such rejections are not tracked against a user otherwise it reflects badly on me and I have no way of providing feedback about it.